# how to test constants in module?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following module:

```
 angular.module('config', []).constant('myconstant', somevalue);
```

I would like to unit test this so I created:

```
describe('Constants', function () {
  var config;

  beforeEach( inject(function (_config_) {
    module('config');
    config =_config_;
  }));

  it('should return settings',function(){
    expect(config.constant('myConstant')).toEqual('somevalue');
  });

});
```

Getting an error now:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configProvider <- config
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a constant...it should have zero behavior and it shouldn't be changing.  Why do you want to test it?  This seems like the wrong place to focus your testing efforts.

Comment: Your right dude what was I thinking

Answer (score 6):

You should be injecting your constant like any other service and not your module. This works for me:

angular.module('config', []).constant('myconstant', 'somevalue');

```
describe('Constants', function () {
      var myconstant;

      beforeEach(module('config'));

      beforeEach( inject(function (_myconstant_) {
          myconstant =_myconstant_;
      }));

      it('should return settings',function(){
        expect(myconstant).toEqual('somevalue');
      });

    });
```